# Can't use font in corona simulator

Tags: fonts, lua, coronasdk, default, simulator

I cant use fonts on the simulator. Every font I downlod do not work, and I did exactly what said here: https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/system/customFont/index.html
and now when I upgraded corona (from 2014.2511 to 2015.2646) it makes even more problems. before it just showd the Default font of my computer, and now it does not show nothing or does other problems. the only font that ever worked is "Eras Light Itc".
why???
(Im using Windows)

Comment: When ever you download a font file, first install that in your PC and restart your Pc. Then follow the steps provided in the corona docs.

Comment: It dosen't worked...

Comment: What is your machine? Mac or Windows?